# Struct with pointer to struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

i have this block of code in a header file, i try to create a struct with inside a pointer to an other struct

```
#ifndef CAMERA_H
#define CAMERA_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "azioni.h"

typedef struct Camera{
    int nrtCamera;
    char * nomeCliente;
    Camera * next;
    Azioni * headAzioni;
} camera;



#endif
```

my problem is that when i try to compile it gives me this error

```
In file included from Test.c:1:0:
camera.h:11:2: error: unknown type name ‘Camera’
  Camera * next;
  ^
camera.h:12:2: error: unknown type name ‘Azioni’
  Azioni * headAzioni;
```

i have also an other header file where i declare the struct Azioni and it gives me the same problem.
How can it be solved?

Comment: Use the proper namespace for the Struct` tag `Camera` inside the definition. The structure definition is not completed at that point (note this is C, not C++.

Comment: because you're creating a camera.h file, I'm assuming the camera struct is meant to be used through an API of sorts. In that case, wouldn't it make more sense just to have the `typedef` in your header (`typedef struct Camera camera;`), and keep the struct implementation opaque/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've use the same pattern for the definition of `azioni` as was used for `camera`, i.e. that you have it defined as something like

```
struct Azioni {
  int some_field1;
  int some_field2;
  int etc;
} azioni;
```

then your definition for Camera could either be

```
typedef struct Camera{
  int nrtCamera;
  char * nomeCliente;
  struct Camera * next;
  struct Azioni * headAzioni;
} camera;
```

or perhaps

```
typedef struct Camera{
  int nrtCamera;
  char * nomeCliente;
  struct Camera * next;
  azioni * headAzioni;
} camera;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks, i went with the first one and it worked!